# Why my extrude always scaled to 1

Tags: edit-mode, extrude

so i try to extrude some edge 
but now if i try to extrude some faces or edges 
it always scaled to 1 
cant doing smooth extrude 


this is capture of my error 
[image: Always scaled to 1]

Answer (score 3):

You have some kind of snap turned on, click on this button to deactivate[image]